# jenkins mac slave docker path not correct

Tags: macos, jenkins

I have jenkins that run on windows and i have mini mac slave that i connect to him with ssh.
when I'm define in jenkins slave configuration a new Environment variables

> name: PATH
>
> value:$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

as it should be on the mac
but when i connect from job in jenkins to mac and print $PATH
I got

> /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

how can I fix this issue